# want to make page array inside the arraylist of asyntack

Tags: android

I have nested json array and i have performed through asynck task I have little bit confusion on this part
I want to make page array inside the arraylist of asynctask but it shows the problem in the page array.
 
All the looped page array are shown in one array i want to make page arraylist inside the arraylist

plz help thank u

```
public class AsynckTask1 extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    String jsonValue;
    GetMagazineData getMagazineData;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<MagazineData> arrayList;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String url;
    public AsynckTask1(Context context, GetMagazineData getMagazineData)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.getMagazineData=getMagazineData;
        arrayList=new ArrayList<MagazineData>();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       /*progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();*/
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result="";
        StringBuilder sp=new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            //Document doc= Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            URL url=new URL(params[0]);
          HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
           // Elements elements=doc.select("p");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            while ((jsonValue=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sp.append(jsonValue).append("\r\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            return sp.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if(!s.equals(""))
        {
            try{
                JSONObject object=new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray dataArray=object.getJSONArray("data");
                ArrayList<String> pageArray=new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> issueArray=new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> total_pagesArray=new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> contentArray=new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject object1=dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    MagazineData magazineData=new MagazineData(); String issue=object1.getString("issue");
                    String total_pages=object1.getString("total_pages");
                    String highlights=object1.getString("highlights");
                    String publish_date=object1.getString("publish_date");
                    ArrayList<String>[] imagesArray=(ArrayList<String>[])new ArrayList[Integer.parseInt(total_pages)];
                    ArrayList<String> contentArrayList;
                    issueArray.add(issue);
                    total_pagesArray.add(total_pages);
                    JSONArray array=object1.getJSONArray("magazine_contents");
                    for(int j=0;j<array.length();j++){
                        JSONObject contentObject=array.getJSONObject(j);

                        String page=contentObject.getString("page");
                        imagesArray[j]=new ArrayList<String>();
                        contentArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
                        ////////modifing....................................
                        //Toast.makeText(context,page,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pageArray.add(page);
                        magazineData.setPage(pageArray);
                        JSONObject textObject=contentObject.getJSONObject("text");
                        if(textObject.length()>0) {
                            for (int text = 0; text < textObject.length(); text++) {
                                String  content=textObject.getString("content");

                                contentArray.add(content);

                            }
                        }


                        //Toast.makeText(context,content,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        JSONArray galleryArray=textObject.getJSONArray("gallery");


                        if(galleryArray.length()>0) {
                            for (int galleryIndex = 0; galleryIndex < galleryArray.length(); galleryIndex++) {
                                JSONObject imageObject = galleryArray.getJSONObject(galleryIndex);
                                String image = imageObject.getString("image");
                                imagesArray[j].add(image);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                            imagesArray[j].add("null");

                        magazineData.setGallerySize(galleryArray.length());
                        magazineData.setContent(contentArray);
                        magazineData.setImage(imagesArray);
                    }

                    magazineData.setHighlights(highlights);
                    magazineData.setPublish_date(publish_date);
                    magazineData.setTotal_pages(total_pagesArray);
                    magazineData.setIssue(issueArray);


                    arrayList.add(magazineData);
                }


                getMagazineData.getAsynckMagazineData(arrayList);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is page array?

Comment: i have made a arraylist pageArray

Comment: i have made arraylist pageArray